# Angularjs - failed to load template - url is close, but missing the virtual directory name

Tags: angularjs, templates

I have deployed my angular application across 2 load balanced web servers.  Sometimes the templates load up, other times they don't, as the url is wrong - the virtual directory name is missing.

Looking at the headers for the template request, I can see the referer is

`http://mysite/folderInIIS/VirtualDirectoryName`

when the templates are searched for the Request URL used is

`http://mysite/folderInIIS/Templates/myTemplate.html`

which fails

If I edit this to:

`http://mysite/folderInIIS/VirtualDirectoryName/Templates/myTemplate.html`

I find my template.

So, because this is periodically occurring, I think one of the web servers has been set up incorrectly, and the load balancer will determine which one you go to and whether or not you will see the error.

**But what would cause the template url to be crafted without the virtual directory name in the path?**

A cut from my directive showing the templateUrl:

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {split : '&', collapseUp: '&', collapseDown: '&'},        
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'Templates/collapseTemplate.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
            var panes = $scope.panes = [];
            var splitterControl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `<base href="..." /> in the`` section of the page, like:

```
<base href="http://mysite/folderInIIS/VirtualDirectoryName" />
```

---

Of course if you want it work on both the local testing environment (no virtual directory) and the server (in virtual directory), you need to dynamically compute the base href.

For example, in .NET MVC, you can use:

```
<base href="@Url.Content("~")" />
```

Hope it helps.